# instantiate a template class with a template parameter of another class

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to instantiate a template class ("A" in the example) with the template parameter of another class?

example:

class "A":

```
//A.h
template <size_t size> 
class A
{
  void doSmt()
  {
     // do something with size
  }
};
```

class "B":

```
//B.h
#include "A.h"
template<typename V>
class B
{
  void doSmt2(A<V> a)  //Error Here
  {
    //do something with a
  }
};
```

Error I got:
Error   1

```
error C2993: 'V' : illegal type for non-type template parameter 'size'
```

Comment: Wait, maybe I'm misunderstanding. Are you wanting to ensure that `doSmt2` is called with an `A` which uses the same template argument, or are you wanting to somehow deduce the argument of `B` from `A`? Can you post how you want to create your `A` and `B` instances?

Comment: No, your answer is exactly what I needed. Maybe the example I made is a bit misleading. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Your issue is that `V` is a type parameter, whereas `size` is a `size_t` parameter. Just make them match.

```
template <std::size_t V>
class B
{
    void doSmt2(A<V> a)
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The template type of A is a **non-type** template parameter.  In `B` we have a type template parameter.  These are not compatible.  What you need to do is add the non-type template parameter type to `B`

```
template<size_t size>
class B
{
  void doSmt2(A<size> a)
  {
    //do something with a
  }
};
```